# Phone Gap Facebook Plugin not working properly via native Facebook App and getLoginStatus() is giving Unknown Status on Android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using phonegap-facebook-plugin to share the feed dialog in my Ionic app. I am testing this with the test users of my app generated in Facebook developer account. This plugin is not sharing the feed via native Facebook app installed on phone. When I don't have the native Facebook app it works fine. But we want to implement this through native Facebook app. 
Second when I am trying to use the method getLoginStatus() and test user is logged in Facebook app then it is giving me response "unknown". But this response should not be there as I am already logged in. For your reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first generate the right key hash and put it on Facebook developer account. And then if you are getting 4201 error use this -
Goto plugin.xml file of Cordova Facebook. Change the $APP_ID and $APP_name with the App Id and App name. It worked for me.